# Extension-point is no longer shown after deployment to sapui5 abap repository

Tags: sapui5

probably I do something very stupid but I can't seem to find my error.

I created a generic application with an extension point in my view and I created a specific application in which I created the fragment which should be shown in the extension point.

When I run my specific application as a Web application via the Web IDE, all works fine and the text 'test' is displayed correctly.

When I run my deployed specific application (deployed to SAPUI5 ABAP REPOSITORY) via the launchpad, the extension-point is nowhere to be found in my HTML which tells me it wasn't loaded at all.

View Generic app

```
<VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
   <Text text="Update"/>
   <core:ExtensionPoint name="owner-information--block"/>
   <Table>
   ...
   </Table>
<VBox>
```

In my specific application I've implemented the extension point with a simple text as example:

Fragment extension-point in Specific app

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" xmlns="sap.m">
   <Text text="test"/>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Manifest specific app

```
"extends": {
   "component": "namespace",
   "extensions": {
     "sap.ui.viewExtensions": {
        "namespace.genericapp.view.View": {
           "owner-information--block": {
            "className": "sap.ui.core.Fragment",
            "fragmentName": "namespace.specificapp.view.fragments.Owner-information",
            "type": "XML"
           }
        }         
     }         
   }
}
```